# Find closest div inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample:

```
<div class="table_cover">
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
</div>
```

When i click "column_expand_list" i need to find closest "element". I have a function, but I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
console.log($(this).parent().parent().closest('.element'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Leave out two `.parent()` calls and apply `.closest()` directly, that should work! With your code you will end up one parent-level too "high".

Comment: A think at this point of code $(this).parent().parent() you get .table_cover element

Comment: @cars10m
console.log($(this).parent().closest('.element'));
And
console.log($(this).closest('.element'));
Doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not see tht at first. Look at my answer below.

Comment: When a method doesn't do what you *expect* it to do, based on your understanding of the name of that method (in this case you're mixing "closest" with "nearest"), then it's time to review the docs:  https://api.jquery.com/closest/  *get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and **traversing up** through its ancestors* - so `closest` in jquery terms means `nearest matching of parents`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use one `.parent` to go back [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the `div.element` - you are using parent `twice` which takes you out of the actual parent `table_cover` div

Using `.next()` like this:

```
$(this).parent('div').next('.element').text()
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.column_expand_list').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent('div').next('.element').text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table_cover">
  <div class="table_element">
    <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">YAY 1</div>

  <div class="table_element">
    <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">YAY 2</div>

  <div class="table_element">
    <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">YAY 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML there is no `closest` element with the class `element`. You can get the closest `.table_element` and from this element you can then navigate to the `next()` or `prev()` `.element`

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) only traveres the DOM in the UP direction, that's why you can't find it from the clicked element you are on.

```js
$('.column_expand_list').on('click', function() {
   console.log($(this).closest('.table_element').next('.element'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table_cover">
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is just a repetition od @Cloned and @AlwaysHelping's answers, but anyway, here it is:

```js
$(".column_expand_list").click(function(){console.log($(this).closest(".table_element").prev()[0])})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table_cover">
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X this will not find a suitable "parent"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY 1</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X click here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY 2</div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <div class="column_expand_list">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">YAY</div>
</div>
```